# sql query for update multiple column by 1

Tags: mysql

I want to increment by 1 for some columns(unique) value of rows in range and I run this;

```
update policy set ORDERNUMBER = ORDERNUMBER +1 where ORDERNUMBER between 3 and 5
```

but it throws duplicate entry error. But there wont be duplicate if query completely run

```
ORDERNUMBER
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want this after query:

```
ORDERNUMBER
1
2
4
5
6
```

Comment: There is nothing between 5 and 3. But there are numbers between 3 and 5.

Comment: I got the point now, but the column is unique so only one point left .. simple way to achieve this :)

Comment: INSERT INTO policy (ORDERNUMBER) VALUES (NULL); DELETE FROM policy ORDER BY ORDERNUMBER LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pete say there is no way of doing this with uniqe constaint column so remove or disable it than make your own; in my scenario I handle this with like this:

```
 try {
            $dbObject = Connection::getConnection();
            $request = $dbObject->dbh->prepare($sqlForOrderNum);
            $request->execute();
            $currentorder = $request->fetchColumn();
            if ($currentorder >= $policyObject->getOrdernumber())
                $sql = "update policy set ORDERNUMBER = ORDERNUMBER +1 where ORDERNUMBER BETWEEN " . $policyObject->getOrdernumber() . " and $currentorder-1" . $sql;
            else
                $sql = "update policy set ORDERNUMBER = ORDERNUMBER -1 where ORDERNUMBER BETWEEN  $currentorder+1 and " . $policyObject->getOrdernumber() . $sql;
            $request = $dbObject->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $request->bindParam(':id', $policyid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $request->bindParam(':policyname', $policyObject->getPolicyName(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $request->bindParam(':remark', $policyObject->getRemark(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $request->bindParam(':access', $policyObject->getAccess(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $request->bindParam(':enablelog', $policyObject->getEnableLog(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the 5 and 3 so it reads:

```
update policy set ORDERNUMBER = ORDERNUMBER +1 where ORDERNUMBER between 3 and 5
```

UPDATE:
ORDERNUMBER appears to have a unique constraint. You can't simply add one to it because then it would have the same value as another row. This operation cannot easily be done with a query like this.

Comment: then it thows duplicate enry error cause unique constaint :) ordernumber is unique

Comment: Duplicate enty error. it same with between query but column has constaint